# How to create new array base on JSON value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i have question about array, for example i have an array of object, like this

```
const data = [
  {
    level: 1,
    name: "Naruto",
  },
  {
    level: 2,
    name: "Dragon",
  },
  {
    level: 2,
    name: "Ball",
  },
  {
    level: 3,
    name: "Sasuke",
  },
]
```

Now  i want to create new array base on `level` , mean that after format it will look like this:

```
[
  [
    {
      name: "naruto"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      name: "Ball"
    },
    { name: "Dragon" }
  ],
  [
    {name:"Sasuke"}
  ]
];
```

How can i do this, thanks you guys

Comment: what have you tried so far? look into `groupBy` commands in javascript, they are going to give similar results, which you can manipulate into your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried with maps but it return each element with seperate array

Comment: try this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/groupBy , it will not give you the exact result, however you can manipulate the result from the `groupBy` to the result that you require

Comment: I tried but it said groupBy not a function

Comment: oh, then your js must be slightly outdated, it was only recently introduced, here you go, use these implementation instead, https://edisondevadoss.medium.com/javascript-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key-afc85c35d07e

Answer (score 1):

I used a loop to handle your case

`currentLevel - 1` is mapped with the index of the result's array

```js
const data = [{
    level: 1,
    name: "Naruto",
  },
  {
    level: 2,
    name: "Dragon",
  },
  {
    level: 2,
    name: "Ball",
  },
  {
    level: 3,
    name: "Sasuke",
  },
];

let result = []
for (const currentValue of data) {

  const currentLevel = currentValue.level

  if (!result[currentLevel - 1]) {
    result[currentLevel - 1] = []
  }

  result[currentLevel - 1].push({
     name: currentValue.name
  })
}

//it's followed by index, the result will have some `undefined` if your levels have gaps. You can comment it out, if you want to keep `undefined` values
result = result.filter(item => item)

console.log({
  result
})
```